# Need to request the user to type in password after login through password?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, membership

Right now I am working on a  member system.

And for common login process, it has facebook login.

The problem is:

**1) Does the common behavior require the user to enter the password for their account?**

Refer to Stackoverflow here, the user doesn't need to enter the password for their account.

So

**2) What will the data structure for the member table be if a user doesn't need to enter his/her password?**

e.g.

```
member
-------
user_data 
password null
salt null
facebook_id null
email
```

Does this look correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: in my opinion, yes no need of password as far its not violating privacy law, stackover doesn't require password to login but also not sharing email address on profile page. it totally depend what kind of site you are developing and what kind of information you can show and not show so you don't violate privacy law and don't help data collecting companies to collect user data from your site which they can sale later

Comment: if no need of password then how to handle the forget password case? Thanks a lot

Comment: You used word Need when refereing to stackoverflow so i share my opinion in same phrase, so password yes or no, up to you and if there is no password why would be need of 'forget password case' even first place.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing here, but you should let the user enter their password through the normal Facebook login flow.